# Remove a row from a data-frame if three of the columns already appear in another row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the populations of cities. In that data I am storing the city name, county, and state. Unfortunately, in my data there are duplicates of an entry. The duplicates are not exactly the same as they may contain slightly different coordinates for the location of the city or a slightly different population. So the typical `distinct()` won't work here. Is there away that I can go through and remove other rows with the same city, county, and state but not care if other variables are unique or shared?

Comment: Try this `df[!duplicated(df[,c('city','country', 'state')]),]`

Comment: @deepseefan Thank you! This worked. Could you please help me understand what this does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain my comment and turn it to an answer as per your request:-

```r
df[!duplicated(df[,c('city','country', 'state')]),]
```

> `df[,c('city','country', 'state')]`

Subsets all rows of the column `city`, `country` and `state`. A subset in `r` works as `data_frame[row, column]`. Leaving the `row` selector empty returns all row in the dataframe, and since we're passing multiple columns we wrap it inside a `c()`.

> `!duplicated()`

returns a logical vector `TRUE` if `city`, `country` and `state` are not a duplicate or `FALSE` if it is a duplicate.

Then we wrap that inside a `df` as a `row selector` and return all `columns`.

> `df[!duplicated(df[,c('city','country', 'state')]),]`

`!duplicated(df[,c('city','country', 'state')])` will serve as a row selector and leaving the column selector empty will return all the columns. `!` is a negative marker by the way.

In short all columns where `!duplicated(df[,c('city','country', 'state')])` is `TRUE` (rows which are not duplicates) will be returned.

Hope you can build on that.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your help is greatly appreciated. I will freely admit that I am not very good at statistics...